# Why does adding an If-statement inside a this method slow it down so drastically?

Tags: java, android, performance

I came across this in [answering another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233594/faster-way-to-apply-alpha-to-a-jpeg-in-an-android-app). I was trying to diagnose which code change had a greater effect on the speed. I used a boolean flag in a for loop to switch between using helper methods to construct a [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html).

The interesting behavior is that when I decided which one was faster and removed the if the speed of the code amplified 10x. Taking 140ms before and just 13ms afterward. I should only be removing one calculation out of about 7 from the loop. Why such a drastic increase in speed?

<strike>**Slow code:** (runs in 141 milliseconds when `helperMethods` is false)</strike> *See edit 2

```
public static void applyAlphaGetPixels(Bitmap b, Bitmap bAlpha, boolean helperMethods) {
    int w = b.getWidth();
    int h = b.getHeight();
    int[] colorPixels = new int[w*h];
    int[] alphaPixels = new int[w*h];
    b.getPixels(colorPixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    bAlpha.getPixels(alphaPixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    for(int j = 0; j < colorPixels.length;j++){
        if(helperMethods){
            colorPixels[j] = Color.argb(Color.alpha(alphaPixels[j]), Color.red(colorPixels[j]), Color.green(colorPixels[j]), Color.blue(colorPixels[j]));
        } else colorPixels[j] = alphaPixels[j] | (0x00FFFFFF & colorPixels[j]);
    }
    b.setPixels(colorPixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
}
```

**Fast Code:** (Runs in 13ms)

```
public static void applyAlphaGetPixels(Bitmap b, Bitmap bAlpha) {
    int w = b.getWidth();
    int h = b.getHeight();
    int[] colorPixels = new int[w*h];
    int[] alphaPixels = new int[w*h];
    b.getPixels(colorPixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    bAlpha.getPixels(alphaPixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    for(int j = 0; j < colorPixels.length;j++){
        colorPixels[j] = alphaPixels[j] | (0x00FFFFFF & colorPixels[j]);
    }
    b.setPixels(colorPixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
}
```

**EDIT:** It seems the issue is not with the fact that the if is inside the loop. If I elevate the `if` outside of the loop. The code runs slightly faster but still at the slow speeds with 131ms:

```
public static void applyAlphaGetPixels(Bitmap b, Bitmap bAlpha, boolean helperMethods) {
    int w = b.getWidth();
    int h = b.getHeight();
    int[] colorPixels = new int[w*h];
    int[] alphaPixels = new int[w*h];
    b.getPixels(colorPixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    bAlpha.getPixels(alphaPixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    if (helperMethods) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colorPixels.length;j++) {
            colorPixels[j] = Color.argb(Color.alpha(alphaPixels[j]),
                                        Color.red(colorPixels[j]),
                                        Color.green(colorPixels[j]),
                                        Color.blue(colorPixels[j]));
        }
    } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < colorPixels.length;j++) {
             colorPixels[j] = alphaPixels[j] | (0x00FFFFFF & colorPixels[j]);
        }
    }

    b.setPixels(colorPixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
}
```

**EDIT 2:** I'm dumb. Really really dumb. Earlier in the call stack I used another boolean flag to switch between between using this method and using another method that uses `getPixel` instead of `getPixels`. I had this flag set wrong for all of my calls that have the `helperMethod` parameter. When I made new calls to the version without `helperMethod` I did it correct. The performance boost is because of `getPixels` not the if statement.

**Actual Slow code:**

```
public static void applyAlphaGetPixel(Bitmap b, Bitmap bAlpha, boolean helperMethods) {
    int w = b.getWidth();
    int h = b.getHeight();
    for(int y=0; y < h; ++y) {
        for(int x=0; x < w; ++x) {
            int pixel = b.getPixel(x,y);
            int finalPixel;
            if(helperMethods){
                finalPixel = Color.argb(Color.alpha(bAlpha.getPixel(x,y)), Color.red(pixel), Color.green(pixel), Color.blue(pixel));
            } else{
                finalPixel = bAlpha.getPixel(x,y) | (0x00FFFFFF & pixel);
            }
            b.setPixel(x,y,finalPixel);
        }
    }
}
```

*Note:All speeds are an average of 100 runs.*

Comment: The if-statement probably makes the code a lot harder to optimize.

Comment: Branching / Branch prediction ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array

Comment: Use Traceview to determine exactly what is taking up your time.

Comment: Traceview will probably fool you since that will disable JIT.

Comment: please provide much more detailed information. In which case is what how fast? Just removed the if or the if and the body of it?

Comment: Btw, aren't you suppose to use
colorPixels[j] = alphaPixels[j] << 24 | (0x00FFFFFF & colorPixels[j]);
instead of 
colorPixels[j] = alphaPixels[j] | (0x00FFFFFF & colorPixels[j]);

Comment: `helperMethods` is true/false for the entire loop. So it can't be branch prediction.

Comment: @auslen No because then I would be setting the trailing bits to the alpha bits. I want use the bits in the same location

Comment: A good enough JIT may be able to notice in the fast code that all you are doing is copying every fourth byte.

Comment: To be clear: are you comparing times when `helperMethods` is `true` or `false` against the "fast code"?

Comment: @Sam I that is what I created the method to do. Running it with it `false` ran about 6ms faster than with it `true`. The time I'm comparing the fast code to is the time when it is `false`

Comment: Which android version is this?

Comment: Android 4.0.4, The times I gave were on an Optimus S with an AOSP build.

Comment: @Fr33dan does manual loop unrolling improve the speed?

Comment: @veer I'm not sure how I could cleanly unroll it without adding if statements.

Comment: I run this on my device and I get similar numbers, I don't see a big difference like 10x.

Comment: That is very peculiar. Can you try installing my APK so we can figure out if it's my device or my code? http://fr33dan.com/AndroidSandbox.apk

Comment: You should be able to answer this question for yourself, by [*this method*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/317160/23771). If you're seeing a 10:1 difference in speed, that means the slow one is spending 90% of its time doing something else. So if you just interrupt it a few times, the chance is 90% that you will see the problem each time you interrupt it. (I would want to double-check the possibility that `helperMethods` might actually be *true*.)

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Your solution would work on a desktop environment but there I'm not aware of a way to do it on an android device. Also this method assumes that the stack is being taken away from my code. If this was the case would it have not shown up when I ran through the code with the debugger?

Comment: @Fr33dan: Sorry, I'm no Android expert. Not sure I understand what you mean by stack being taken away. Regardless, isn't there a way to run Android code under an emulator or something, so you can interrupt it and really see what's going on? Or do they just make it a *&*&$& black box?

Comment: Numbers were ~200 versus ~15. Can you share the source code somewhere?

Comment: @auselen Interesting, this must mean the `Bitmap` setup must have some effect on how the execution runs, which makes even less sense to me since that code was consistent. Here is a copy of the source that generates the problem: http://www.fr33dan.com/AndroidSandbox.zip

Comment: @Fr33dan It is probably your timing. You start timer too early, and load bitmaps in the tests which are getting effected by GCs of previous test runs. You update ui while next test is running. When I clear your code to get just what you describe above, in the result I see similar numbers, no big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably your profiling code, that confusing you. Try to isolate the part of the code that you want to profile and just measure that part, avoid GCable operations like creating Bitmaps in your cases.

If I call your test code with

```
testing.loadDrawable(this, false, true, false)
```

it runs slow. But if I call it with

```
testing.loadDrawable(this, true, true, false)
```

That's a similar (still worse) number. So useGetPixels makes all the difference. Which I guess gets the Bitmap data into a local buffer and set the results later.

Comment: If the problem was the GC wouldn't that mean only the first run would be fast since only the later ones would be bogged down by the GC clearing the earlier test? Also this is the biggest performance impact I've heard of as a result of the GC and it seems to have come out of nowhere. How can I predict when the GC will cause such massive problems? This feels like I'm getting close to the answer, but I'd still like to know exactly what's going on.

Comment: In this answer I don't claim problem is due to GCs but your code is too messy and doesn't do the profiling correctly. I believe your problem is `useGetPixels`, when you enable it run time increases. Otherwise `if` as you clain doesn't change run time.

Comment: So I'm confused. You are saying getPixels had an increased run time? For me it was faster every time. You're the "fast" version is `loadDrawableHard(this,true,true)`. I changed the name so I would be able to tell easily which was the hard coded one. In this version all the code is the same except the `applyAlphaGetPixelsHard()` and 'applyGetPixelHard()` are called instead. If I run it with `useGetPixels` set to false I don't see the same improvement. I originally wrote `loadDrawableHard()` to only use `applyAlphaGetPixelsHard()` but added `applyGetPixelHard()` to remove a possible differences.

Comment: I cannot believe what I did. If you look at all my calls they all have `useGetPixels` set to false. Nothing wrong with my profiling code, I've just been profiling the wrong thing the whole stupid time.

Comment: This was all I tried to say from the beginning however I guess you had to see it to understand. When I say your profiling code is confusing you, I wanted to say that code was too messy, making it for hard to see how you call those functions. GC thing was just a side notice.

Answer (score 4):

Try hoisting the condition out of the loop:

```
if (helperMethods) {
    for (int j = 0; j < colorPixels.length;j++) {
        colorPixels[j] = Color.argb(Color.alpha(alphaPixels[j]),
                                    Color.red(colorPixels[j]),
                                    Color.green(colorPixels[j]),
                                    Color.blue(colorPixels[j]));
    }
} else {
    for (int j = 0; j < colorPixels.length;j++) {
         colorPixels[j] = alphaPixels[j] | (0x00FFFFFF & colorPixels[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very interesting. It seems to be acting the same. Runs with `helperMethods` false in 143ms.

Comment: Branch prediction should handle it really well though... hmm.

Answer (score 2):

In the 'fast code' you never run the statement

```
colorPixels[j] = Color.argb(Color.alpha(alphaPixels[j]), Color.red(colorPixels[j]), Color.green(colorPixels[j]), Color.blue(colorPixels[j]));
```

But in the 'slow code' if the boolean is set to true at least once you run this addiotional statement that makes the time longer. If your condition is always false then the if statement is checked about 7 times in each iteration through the loop. Try to place the if outside the loop.

Comment: I've tried that, the code still runs at roughly the slow time. It's 8ms faster.

Comment: it's interesting. Big-O analysis... :)

Comment: I don't think it's technically Big-O since that's defined by the number of time an algorithm runs compared to the dataset.

Comment: right. however it must be something that consumes that time probably somewhere in the lower level which sounds as bug for me

Answer (score 0):

In your fast code you don't use class Color at all. I assume initialization of this class takes some time, it has lots of static method and static code.

You can try to do following: 
make sure Color class is fully loaded and initialized before making your test (you can call any static method from Color class before calling your applyAlphaGetPixels() method). Then run your test and compare results.

Comment: Wouldn't this only effect the first time the test is run within an instance of the program?

Comment: Most likely it should affect only first run in the production program, but it could affect differently in your test runs